# JavaScript audio object addEventListener canplaythrough not working on IPAD Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ipad, html5-audio

I have two functions in `JavaScript`. Its working fine on `Windows 7` `Chrome` but  `loadedAudio_chrome` function is not being fired on `IPAD`.

```
function preloadAudio_chrome(url)
{
  try 
  {
       var audio = new Audio();
       audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', loadedAudio_chrome, false);
       //audio.src = filePath;
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}

function loadedAudio_chrome()
{
   //alert('not firing this alert on IPAD');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing **audio.load()** from your snippet, try adding that as shown below and it should work.

```
function preloadAudio_chrome(url)
{
  try 
  {
       var audio = new Audio();
       audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', loadedAudio_chrome, false);
   // EDIT HERE ADD audio.load();
       audio.load();
  } catch (e) {
   alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi waqas `addEventListener` is not being fired in IPAD chrome. Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: This works now it fires `loadedAudio_chrome` successfully.